# Silverlight, WCF Ria, EF, flow

Tags: wcf, silverlight, entity-framework, security

Can someone please explain to my how the flow is when i have a Silverlight Application that uses WCF Ria and Entity framework. So I better understand where to secure the transport of information.

I think of it as, the user enter the website and the silverlight application is downloaded to the users computer. Then if the user what to create a new entry, he enter the details, and then a new instance of the service is create. The service is on the web project with the silverlight application. Then the information is sent to the webservice on the web project, and from the webservice the information is sent to the server where the DAL is.
All the information is sent in XML.
And i have to secure it from the user to the web service, and from the webservice to the server where the DAL is.

Am I right, or is it completely wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way I founded to cypher data between client and server with WCF was setting the EnableClientAccess to require a secure endpoint in the DomainService:

```
[EnableClientAccess(RequiresSecureEndpoint = true)]
public partial class DomainService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<YourEntities>
```

Comment: Thats also my guess. Do you know anything about the architecture i descriped?

Comment: What do you want to know? You can see the data you are sending through the net by using fiddler. You'll see how the client calls a web service with the parameters you set... and it returns the info you asked for 8-)